# Losing Cart when guest registers

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, register, persistent

Title says it all. Persistent Shopping Cart settings are as follows:

```
Enable Persistence
Yes
Persistence Lifetime (seconds)
31536000
Enable "Remember Me"
Yes
"Remember Me" Default Value
Yes
Clear Persistence on Log Out
No
Persist Shopping Cart
Yes
```

This problem only occurs when a guest registers, logging into an account that had previously been created works just fine.

Please let me know if I need to provide further details or any specific code.

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you have some custom code or extension which is conflicting here. Magento have an event "`sales_quote_merge_before`" before merging the cart for login user.

Please find this event in your code, might be that will help you.

Comment: Any method you would recommend to search for this code?

Comment: search this string "sales_quote_merge_before" in your code directory and check if any custom extension using this.